# Differences between Training Data and Vocabulary - Bag Of Words

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

When creating a Bag Of Words, you need to create a `Vocabulary` to give to the `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` to which you use on the images you wish to input. This creates the `Testing Data`.

So where does the `Training Data` come from, and where do you use it?

Whats the difference between `Vocabulary` and `Training Data`?

Isn't the `Vocabulary` the same thing as the `Training Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Training data* is a set of images you collected for your application as the input of `BOWTrainer`, and *vocabulary* is the output of the `BOWTrainer`. Once you have the *vocabulary*, you can extract features of images using `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` with the *words* defined in the *vocabulary*.

An image can be described by tons of features (*words*), however only some of them are important. The first job to do is to find those important *words*, that is, to train a *vocabulary*. After the *vocabulary* is obtained, images can be described more precisely.

> So where does the `Training Data` come from, and where do you use it?

You should provide the *Training data*, and use it to train the *vocabulary* with `BOWTrainer`. The *Training data* is a set of images (descriptors), depends on your application domain.

> What's the difference between `Vocabulary` and `Training Data`?

*Vocabulary* is cooked, while *training data* is raw, unorganized.

> Isn't the `Vocabulary` the same thing as the `Training Data`?

No.

Comment: Damn son, mighty fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an add function that is used to specify training data. [docs on opencv bow module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html)